# matplotlib's scatter module does not behave as expected with "color" and "marker" options in 3D plots

Tags: matplotlib, scatter3d

When using `matplotlib`'s `scatter` module for plotting scattered data on 3D, the options `color` and `marker` do not behave as expected, e.g., 
`color='r', marker='o'` produce blue dots surrounded by red circles, instead of just filled red circles.

Why this is happening?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
x = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)
y = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)
z = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)

##### Plotting:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from the question produces the expected plot with red points in matplotlib 2.0.2. If you have an older version, this may be different.

Other than

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='r', marker='o')
```

You may also try to use the `c` argument, which is usually meant to define the color of a scatter

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
```

You may also use the `facecolors` argument

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, facecolors='r', marker='o')
```